# Attach link to pages accoding to tags

Tags: pages, tags, links

I have a WordPress blog (local installation) and I'm trying to add the following functionality to it:

Suppose I have a page on my blog entitled "Algebra", I want this page to contain a list of links to every post blog that has the tag "algebra" attached to it.
For example, I make a post entitled "Quadratic Equations" and tag it under "algebra", currently I go to the "Algebra" page and add a link to my "Quadratic Equations" post. I would like to make this process automatic.

How can I do that? I couldn't find any plugin to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the code below in single.php file anywhere you want the links to appear in your posts, or inside a function in functions.php and the function tied to a filter or an action like 'the_content', the you shold get a list of links to the posts that have the same tag or tags as the post you are currently reading.

```
 global $post;
    $this_post_tags_ids = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

    $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tag__in' => $this_post_tag_ids ) );
    if ($query->have_posts()){
       while($query->have_posts()){
          $query->the_post();
          echo the_title('<h3><a href="'.get_the_permalink.'"/>', '</a></h3>');
       }
    }

wp_reset_query();
```

I didn't tested it, but it should work.